# TOML parser error in VSCode when installing any Julia package

Tags: julia

When I try to install any package by VSC I'm getting following error. I reinstalled Julia extension, deleted Project/Manifest.toml and even reinstalled VSC but the issue still persist. What steps should be taken to resolve that?

```
(bin) pkg> add Plots
ERROR: Could not parse project: TOML Parser error:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.9.4\bin\julia.exe:1:3 error: invalid bare key character: '\x90'
  MZ��♥���♦���������������@���������������������������������������▼���  �!�☺L�!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
    ^
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980718/toml-parse-error-when-adding-package-in-julia has the same problem. It doesn't offer an explanation for _why_ this happens (which I'm curious about too), but does give a couple of workarounds that might work for you as well.

Comment: thanks Sundar; I did all the proposed solutions but still didn't work; I uninstalled 1.9.4 and simply downgraded to 1.8.5, after that don't expect any issues anymore